# Send parameter to @ModelAttribute annotated method from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following method annotated with `@ModelAttribute`

```
@ModelAttribute(value = "getRelatedNames")
public Map<String, String> getRelatedFormNames(String value) {
    // Logic to get and return the related names
}
```

How can I send the `value` String from the jsp? I have tried

```
<c:forEach var="nameMap" items="${getRelatedNames('testString')}">
    <option value="${nameMap.key}">${nameMap.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

and

```
<c:forEach var="nameMap" items="${getRelatedNames(value = 'testString')}">
    <option value="${nameMap.key}">${nameMap.value}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

but I get the following error:

```
The function getRelatedNames must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to EL version or missing: 
and already has an answer here

1. [The function test must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017348/org-apache-jasper-jasperexception-the-function-test-must-be-used-with-a-prefix)
2. [The function getMessageData must be used with a prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961316/the-function-getmessagedata-must-be-used-with-a-prefix-when-a-default-namespace)